# Narrative flow - word order

Tags: word-choice

Which version sounds more natural and engaging?

When Tom got out of the water, he was still scared but at the same time relieved. Everyone else was laughing at what had happened. **So, he thought aloud,** 'I should have expected this from Sam.' It had been a joke he would never forget.

Or

When Tom got out of the water, he was still scared but at the same time relieved. Everyone else was laughing at what had happened. 'I should have expected this from Sam,' **Tom thought aloud.**  It had been a joke he would never forget.

Comment: In your first version the phrase *So, he thought aloud ...* needs quotation marks around 'So', so *'So', he thought aloud ...*.  Without them 'So' is part of the text, not part of the speech uttered within the text.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure someone smarter than me will come along and give you a more thorough answer, but your quick answer is the second one. I don't know the exact technical reasoning as to *why* it flows better, but I know most people would agree it does. Hope this helps until someone gives you more detail!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: *but I know most people would agree it does* That's a bold claim!

Comment: I kind of agree, but it would be better to explore in more detail, and maybe consider other alternatives too. Otherwise the answer might be useful to the OP (at least in the short term) but doesn't provide a useful resource for others or help anyone become a better writer.